# Pipfileの仕様はどこで定義されていますか？

Tags: python, pipenv

## 環境

- Pipenv 2018.11.26

## 質問

Pipfileの仕様はどこで定義されていますか？

たとえば、以下のようなことを知るために、Pipfileの仕様を知りたいです。

- `url`は何を指しているのか？
- `packages` or `dev-packages`では`path`,`editable`以外に、どんなオプションが利用できるか
- `requests = "*"`のアスタリスクは、何に対してのワイルドカードか？たぶんバージョン？

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]
requests = "*"

[dev-packages]
"e1839a8" = {path = ".", editable = true}
```

https://github.com/pypa/pipfile を見ましたが、特に仕様らしきものは記載されていませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REAME.rst](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/blob/7d7c3126dcfc519d7250c3ed4f311f8e58c3197c/README.rst)にはPipfileのドキュメントが https://pipfile.pypa.io/ に存在する、と記載されていますが、実際には404になるようです。

この件についてはいくつかIssueが立っており、そのうち最新のものは @yuji38kwmt さんが立てたものに見えます。

- [site documentation is not found · Issue #86 · pypa/pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/86)
- [Dead documentation link · Issue #104 · pypa/pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/104#issuecomment-430669154)
- [`https://pipfile.pypa.io/` in `README.rst` is not found · Issue #118 · pypa/pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/118)

さて、ここで#104（Dead documentation link）のIssueについている[コメント](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/104#issuecomment-430669154)を参照すると、他にも詳細なリファレンス仕様を求めている方は複数いるようですが、これに対する回答のようなものは集まっていなさそうです。

このため、現時点では**意味論的な仕様はリファレンスとしては定義されていない**、という回答になります。

但し、意味論的な仕様は[Pipenvの実装](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)を、構文論的な仕様は[Pipfileの実装](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/blob/7d7c3126dcfc519d7250c3ed4f311f8e58c3197c/pipfile/api.py)を読むことで解釈が可能です。

Comment: そういえばissueを立てていましたね。。。このときはリンク切れを報告したただけでして、リンク先がPipfileの仕様だとは認識していませんでした。

Comment: しかし、リンク切れが放置されているのは、なぜでしょう。。。

Comment: READMEによると、 `WARNING: This project is under active design and development. Nothing is set in stone at this point in time.` とのことですので、まだ完全に仕様が固まっているわけではないのが原因なようです。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。